# WPF Dynamic Data Binding in Image source

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic

What i m doing wrong?

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="26*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="63*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="67*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Name ="title" Text="" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Grid.Row="0" Margin="25,10,25,0"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding Path=BindImgURL}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="164" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="306" Margin="152,0,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

C# Code:

```
private string Id;
    private string ImgURL;
    public VideoDetails(string Id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Id = Id;
        DetailsGenerator dg = new DetailsGenerator(Id);
        this.ImgURL = "Dynamic source";
        this.DataContext = BindImgURL;
        MessageBox.Show(BindImgURL);

    }
    public string BindImgURL
    {
        get { return ImgURL; }
        set
        { ImgURL = value; }
    }
```

Displaying Source correct!
checked by MessageBox.But No image 
what i did wrong? I have tried removing "path=" but doesn't worked

Comment: you're setting the `DataContext` to a string. Also your `VideoDetails` is a window? you create it dynamically? because normally a window constructor does not have any parameter (parameterless) because XAML designer does not support window with parameterized constructor. In this case it should be `DataContext = this;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you either want to set `DataContext` to `this`

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

or change binding to current `DataContext`

```
<Image Source="{Binding}" .../>
```

at the moment `Image` will search for `BindImgURL` in current `DataContext`, which is set to `BindImgURL` and that is a `string`

Not related to your problem but I would also suggest you look into implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and raising `PropertyChanged` event for `BindImgURL` as, at the moment, after you set `DataContext` any change to `BindImgURL` won't be picked up by UI